# Can I still use Java EE on Intellij or do I have to use Jakarta EE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, tomcat9

Trying to work on a project that must use Tomcat 9 server but I've discovered that this version of Tomcat doesn't work with Jakarta EE.

Is it still possible to use Java EE for Intellij in 2022?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-ee.html

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it - changed the version from Jakarta EE 9 to Java EE 8.

When creating a new project on the second window where you choose dependencies there's a drop down menu for "version". Choose Java EE 8 instead of Jakarta EE 9.